# Killing a process in a script

Tags: bash

I'm running into a weird behavior for a certain app I'm using.  If I start the command in the background in bash, I can kill it using

```
$ command &
$ kill -n 2 [PID of command]
  killing command gracefully
```

However, when I throw this into a script:

```
command &
ID=$!
kill -n 2 $ID
```

it doesn't do anything at all.  Is there some subtly I'm missing?

Edit: Another clue is that once the script stops running, I can't kill the command using kill -n 2.

Comment: `ID=command&` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: Sorry, got lazy with the abridging of my code. Edited.

Comment: why not use kill -9 $PID

Answer (score 1):

man 7 signal
You are sending a signal 2, INT, to your process, that is Interrupt from keyboard, why ?
People are saying to send a signal 1, why ?

The standard gracefully way to kill a process is signal 15, Termination sigal, that is the default used by kill.

So just use kill "$PID"

Then, in case your process run subprocess, you don't just want to kill the father, but you want to kill them all, so use "-$PID" instead of "$PID" to kill the whole process group, but as kill will think that's -"$PID" is a signal number, it will complain, so you'll have to be more precise, as :

```
kill -15 -"$PID"
```

If the program don't want to die, use kill -9 -"$PID"

```
man 7 signal
man kill
```

Answer (score 0):

If you command outputs to the terminal, bash will stop it with SIGSTOP, which will make it ignore SIGINT you are sending.

Answer (score 0):

Your $ID matches a command string, while what you need is a PID. Maybe try this:

```
 ID=`pidof -s command`
 kill -9 $ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't your problem, but the -n is an option for bash's built-in kill command. I would suggest using -NAME instead so that it works for the actual command too.

Answer (score 0):

Some shells that support job control in interactive mode do not enable job control in scripts by default.  [`set -m`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/set.html) will enable job control.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `wait` command right after your `kill`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in case the command is run from a script, it will handle/ignore some signals. Nevertheless, you can still kill the process with SIGKILL (1) like this:

```
kill -n 1 $ID
```